# EJ2 Java script Server side Pagination

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on EJ2 Javascript grid. which is working fine. But my problem is i am having around 10K + records, if i am loading these into grid, page takes ages to load. So i was thinking to make pagination, for each page i will load 10-20 records, that time load time will decrease. I have checked Ej2 website as well. but i am not able to find any proper manual for that.

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/javascript/demos/#/material/grid/default-paging.html

My current code :

```
var grid = new ej.grids.Grid({
dataSource: data,
allowPaging: true,
allowResizing: true,
showToolbar: true,
allowExcelExport: true,
allowPdfExport: true,
allowSearching: true,
allowFiltering: true,
filterSettings: { type: 'CheckBox' },
columns: [
{ field: 'InvoiceNumber', headerText: 'Test', customAttributes: { class: "customcss" }, 
  textAlign: 'center', width: 100 },
],
});
}
}
grid.appendTo('#tblPo');
```

Where we can pass offset and page records here?

Comment: Have you read [pagesettings](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/api/grid/#pagesettings)?

Comment: yes, i just checked it, but there is no more information on how we can pass to controller and bring from controller

Comment: What's wrong with `pageSettings: { currentPage: 1, pageSize: 12, pageCount: 8, pageSizes: true },` from the documentation?